# Chrome Extension - storing the URL before the request is made, not working?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension.

manifest.json

```json
    {
      "manifest_version": 3,
      "name": "redirect checker",
      "version": "1.0",
      "description": "checks redirects .",
      "action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "redirect checker"
      },
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["content.js"]
        }
      ],
      "background.service_worker": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
      },
      "options_page": "options.html",
      "permissions": ["webRequest", 
                      "webNavigation",
                       "tabs", 
                       "scripting",
                        "activeTab", 
                        "storage", 
                        "contentSettings"],
      "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
      "content_security_policy": {
        "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
      }
    
    }
```

background.js

```js
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function(details) {
          // Save the URL to the storage
          chrome.storage.local.set({ 'initialURL': details.url });
        },
        { urls: ['<all_urls>'] },
        []
      );
```

popup.js

```js
    chrome.storage.local.get('initialURL', function(data) {
      const initialURL = data.initialURL;
      console.log('this URL:', initialURL);
      // Do whatever you want with the URL here
    });
```

The console log says 'this URL: undefined'.

To be clear, I'm trying to get the URL inputted in the address bar before the response is fully complete, I want the initial URL as I have an API I'm going to pass it to in order to then make a URL request and check it for redirects.

Am I using the right thing and why is it saving undefined?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: I think the service worker is not started, so please check.

Comment: how do I check that?

Answer (score 0):

No service worker view.

[image]

Replase

```json
  "background.service_worker": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
```

with

```json
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
```

A view of the service worker exists.

[image]

Comment: The service worker now seems to be working but the URL still isn't the first to be added - it seems to get either a script tag or the previous chrome://extension url